# How to pass JMeter properties through java

Tags: java, jmeter

I am trying to run jmeter through java.
The examples from https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui

I uploaded jmx file like was described in example.

In the jmx file I have properties. Properties specified like ${__property(0_users,,0)}

I manged to upload this property through command line using -J parameter.

How can I specify parameters through java. I didn't find any info regarding this.

Does exist some way to specify it directly in java ? 
        StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

```
    // Initialize Properties, logging, locale, etc.
    JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("C:\\jMeter\\apache-jmeter-2.13\\bin\\jmeter.properties");
    JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("C:\\jMeter\\apache-jmeter-2.13");

    JMeterUtils.initLogging();// you can comment this line out to see extra log messages of i.e. DEBUG level
    JMeterUtils.initLocale();

    // Initialize JMeter SaveService
    SaveService.loadProperties();

    // Load existing .jmx Test Plan
    File jmxFile = new File("C:\\jMeter\\test.jmx");
    HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(jmxFile);

    jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
    jmeter.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

The aforementioned link states:

```
// Initialize Properties, logging, locale, etc
JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("/path/to/your/jmeter/bin/jmeter.properties");
```

So you can define the properties you need directly in *jmeter.properties* or *user.properties* files - they live in Jmeter's "bin" folder like:

```
0_users=50
foo=bar
```

And finally you always have possibility to fall back to [Java Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html). If you plan to create a Java executable you can switch to [__Beanshell()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell) function like:

```
${__BeanShell(System.getProperty("0_users"))}
```

Property value can be provided via `-D` command line argument like:

```
your_binary -D0_users=50
```

or again you can set the value via *system.properties* file.

Remember that you need to have `ApacheJMeter_functions.jar` library in your CLASSPATH in order to properly evaluate any JMeter function.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for comprehensive information on using JMeter properties.

Comment: save all my properties to jmeter.properties file. I can run jmeter from command line without -J parameter. But parameters doesn't retrieve when I run jmeter from Java.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your JMeter test plan and output

Comment: thanks for you response I fix my issue through creating TestPlan through jmeter api.